# async void или как превратить Action в Func<Task>

Tags: c#, .net

Есть некий класс, который принимает в конструктор `Action<object>`. Но мне потребовалось передать туда асинхронный метод (то есть `Func<object, Task>`). Создал наследника и в конструкторе попытался сделать следующее

```
public MyClassAsync(Func<object, Task> execute) :
    base (async (o)=>await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>execute?.Invoke(o)))
{ }
```

Естественно подчеркивает `async` и пишет что

> asynchronous method anonymous should not return void

А чего мне делать то?

Это не ошибка компилятора. Я насколько понимаю это просто предупреждение о том, что компилятор не знает наверняка как себя вести в такой ситуации. То есть мой код скомпилируется, запустится, но я не знаю наверняка, как он отработает.

**UPD:**

Я покажу кое что для примера

Вот https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand(v=vs.110).aspx здесь описание `RelayCommand`

Вот один из конструкторов

```
RelayCommand(Action<Object>, Predicate<Object>)
```

А вот https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.asyncrelaycommand(v=vs.110).aspx
`AsyncRelayCommand : RelayCommand`

и вот соответствующий конструктор

```
AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Object, Task>, Predicate<Object>, Boolean)
```

К сожалению я не знаю, где посмотреть на исходники этого. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что если в базовый конструктор передать `o => Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`, как предложили в комментариях, то я получу неуправляемую задачу, об окончании которой не смогу узнать.

**UPD2**

Итак, в конечном счете у меня должны получиться 2 класса

`RelayCommand` и `AsyncRelayCommand : RelayCommand`

Подразумевается использовать их так

```
public RelayCommand SomeCommand {get;set;}

public RelayCommand SomeAsyncCommand {get;set;}

public Ctor()
{
    SomeCommand = new RelayCommand(AnyMethod, Predicate);
    SomeAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(AnyMethodAsync, Predicate);
}

async Task AnyMethodAsync()
{
    await SomeTask;
    UIMethod(); // я должен быть уверен, что этот метод выполнится в UI потоке. Конечно, предполагается, что задача сработала посредством взаимодействия пользователя с интерфейсом (по нажатию кнопки или хоткея или еще как)
}
```

Не получается определить конструктор для `AsyncRelayCommand`, так как предполагается использование базового конструктора для `RelayCommand`, а он принимает `Action` (ну или `Action<object>`, но это уже вопрос вариативности), а async метод должен быть типа `Func<Task>` (или `Func<object,Task>`)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56929/discussion-on-question-by-irumba-async-void----action--functas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никакой необходимости создавать отдельный класс для запуска асинхронного метода в UI-потоке. Можно использовать для этого обычный RelayCommand если сменить возвращаемое значение на void:

```
public RelayCommand SomeAsyncCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(AnyMethodAsync, Predicate);

async void AnyMethodAsync()
{
    await SomeTask;
    UIMethod();
}
```

Если возврат Task из метода принципиален - то при вызове метода из команды его можно попросту проигнорировать:

```
public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> execute) 
    :base (o => execute(o))
{ }
```

Comment: на `async void` я получаю предупреждение, что так делать атата! Насколько я знаю, метода `async void` нельзя дожидаться через `await`. А есть ли еще какие то ограничения? Я должен быть уверен, что это не создаст сюрпризов.

Comment: @iRumba https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Comment: @iRumba не должно быть такого предупреждения. `async void` - стандартное решение для обработчиков событий.

Comment: @iRumba есть еще особенности обработки исключений в таких методах. Не забудьте повесить обработчик неперехваченных исключений при старте приложения - тогда и сюрпризов не будет.